# Batch file or VBS to edit one charcter

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, helper

I need to use "something", maybe a *.bat or *.vbs or a combination of the two.
Scenario: I have an environment with aprox 200 users.  They have a production environment for a specific application and a test environment for this application also.

There is one file (an *.ini) file that has pulled a "Device ID" from the production environment into the test environment.

That *.ini file in the test environment needs to have one character changed in it for it to work properly in the test environment.  But each of the two hundred pc's will have a different Device ID.

So I need something that will go out to this test environment *.ini and compare it to the production environment *.ini, and replace the Device ID in the test *.ini with a new ID.

Basically all that is changing in the device id, is the second character in the ID will be a "6".

```
D63001000A (within the TEST environment)

D33001000A (production environment)
```

So looks like I need it to change the the first "3" in the ID to a "6" (for the test environment).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways how you could approach this, but I wouldn't recommend fiddling around with replacing single characters in an ID. If you want to go the VBScript route, you could use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29) for storing a mapping of computernames to IDs and use that in the replacement.

```vb
Set deviceIDs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
deviceIDs.Add "computer A", "ID A"
deviceIDs.Add "computer B", "ID B"
deviceIDs.Add "computer C", "ID C"
...

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ini = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.ini").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(device id = ).*"

Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
ini = re.Replace(ini, "$1" & deviceIDs(net.ComputerName))

fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.ini").Write ini
```

If you have the mapping of computer names to device IDs in some other file (e.g. a CSV) you could also use that file for populating the dictionary:

```vb
Set deviceIDs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\device_id.csv")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  id = Split(f.ReadLine, ",")
  deviceIDs.Add id(0), id(1)
Loop
f.Close
```

**Edit:** For replacing a specific character in a specific line you could do something like this:

```vb
lineNumber = 23

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ini = Split(fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.ini").ReadAll, vbNewLine)

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(.{16})3"

ini(lineNumber) = re.Replace(ini(lineNumber), "$16")

fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.ini").Write Join(ini, vbNewLine)
```

Comment: WOW, that's awesome, but I wouldn't know how to do that.  Part of the problem is, we do not know which computer has which ID.  It's a mess..

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know anything about this topic, but what if there was a script that could run; that would open the file, count down to a specific line, then count over 17 characters, then change "3" to "6", save & close?

Comment: Let's just say it is located at: C:\SomeProgram\SubDirectory\test\THIS.ini